# type hinting in python with pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting

I'm trying to use type hinting in python 3.6 with PyCharm 2018.2

It works fine for functions and methods:

```
def foo(x: int) -> int:
    return x + 1
```

However there are no warnings in all of the following cases:

```
a: str = 3

b: int
b = 'b'

class C:
    d: int

    def __init__(self):
        self.d = 'd'
        self.e: str = 3
```

I made sure to check 'type checker' and 'type hints' in the Inspections settings.

[Jetbrains doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html) even uses similar examples

What am I missing?

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out! I didn't find it before.
I'm still confused though, why would jetbrains make examples like this if it isn't supported?

Comment: Beats me. Maybe that's another bug report you could try filing? (This time, it's a bug in their docs). Or maybe variable annotations only work in very specific circumstances in Pycharm? I mostly use mypy, so I'm afraid the best I can do is to just point you to that bug (and I guess recommend using mypy -- or one of the several mypy plugins for pycharm :P).